# PrimeFaces Custom Error pages

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my PrimeFaces project, I need to provide some general error pages for general response error status codes such as 401 and 404. Does somebody know how can I figure this out?

Answer (score 8):

It's not handled by JSF, it's handled by the servlet container. You can specify them by `<error-page>` in `web.xml`.

```html
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/errors/401.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

If you'd like to navigate to them from inside JSF action methods, then you can use [`ExternalContext#responseSendError()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#responseSendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) for this.

```
externalContext.responseSendError(401, "You are not authorized.");
```